# Invalid Memo, OLE, or Hyperlink Object in subquery

Tags: sql, ms-access

Im tryna get an MS Access query to display the top 3 athletes from my dataset, based off of their total points. The total points are in a different table to the athletes and their info, which is making it difficult for me, as i am a noob. Ive got this code which i believe should work;

```
SELECT [m].ChildsName, [m].MembershipType, [r].TotalPoints
FROM [Members] AS m, [Results] AS r
WHERE ([m].[MembershipType]) In 
   (SELECT TOP 3 [m].MembershipType 
    FROM [Members], [Results]
    WHERE ChildsName = m.ChildsName
    ORDER BY [r].TotalPoints DESC, [m].MembershipType)
ORDER BY [m].ChildsName, [r].TotalPoints DESC , [m].MembershipType;
```

Only problem is it doesnt work. it brings up the error:
Invalid Memo, OLE, or Hyperlink Object in subquery '[m].MembershipType'

All this stuff is being pulled from the 2 tables, members and results

Comment: Is this your actual code? Because `[mt].MembershipType` isn't going to work. Please post the actual code, so we don't have to deal with errors caused by transcribing it.

Comment: Yes, your alias are wrongly applied, and joins are (must be) missing. So restart from scratch with two separate and simple select queries, then build steop by step and, when success, combine these.

Comment: join? the [mt] was a mistake, but the rest was the actual code

Comment: Your subquery can't work either, because `[m]` and `[r]` aren't defined there. And the first `ChildsName` isn't qualified at all.

Answer (score 0):

The Memo data type is now called "Long Text".

The problem is that if you have a select within a select you cannot use a memo field so maybe transform your field into short text. Mind that short text is limited to 255 characters afaik.